# Change primary GPU to Intel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu, qemu

I ran into the problem that Ubuntu GNOME automatically uses my Nvidia dedicated GPU as the primary GPU. But because I have to blacklist the device and passthrough it to a VM, I need my integrated Intel GPU as the primary Graphics device. 
I have done some research, but I was not able to find a way without using the Nvidia drivers or switcheroo...

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you already.

(Please excuse my bad english)

System Specs:
Intel i5 3570k
Nvidia GTX 770
DDR3 16 GB
Windows 7 and
Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1